# Error Type mismatch

Tags: vb6

Why am I getting this `Type Mismatch` error?

Code:

```
Dim data as Date

    data = CDate(Format(31, "00") & "/" & Format("1/9/2013", "mm/yyyy"))
```

When I try this with strings of course it works perfect.

Obs: It works if I use a `different day than 31` like 28 for exemple... But Why this error occurs `only with the day 31`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, and it's stupid -.-" `Month 9 = Agost = 30 days and not 31`... I feel so stupid now ;x

Comment: I thought month 9 = September! :(

Comment: kkkk '-'  
I never ever wonder this could be firing the error, omg... First thing I thought was something about the programming itself u.u Geee!

Comment: 30 days hath September, April, June and November.  All the rest have 31, save February Alone; And that has 28 days clear, and 29 in each leap year.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to get the last day of the month.  If that is the case, try this...

```
Dim data As Date
Dim OriginalDate As Date

OriginalDate = DateSerial(2013, 12, 20)

data = DateSerial(Year(OriginalDate), Month(OriginalDate) + 1, 0)
```

This code basically gets the first day of the next month and then subtracts one day.  The nice thing about using the DateSerial function is that you can give it "invalid" values, For example, if you use Year = 2013 and Month = 13, you will get January 2014.

Comment: You can use `DateSerial(Year(OriginalDate), Month(OriginalDate) + 1, 0)` hack instead of `+ 1 - 1` roundtrip. The `Day` parameter can be any positive/negative integer.

Comment: I don't really consider it a hack to add 1, but I do agree that it would be slightly mode efficient so I will modify my answer.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have to watch out for dates because depending on what region your computer is in (Control Panel / Region and Language) sometimes your date of `Format("1/9/2013", "mm/yyyy"))` can be interpreted as `September 1, 2013` or as `January 9, 2013`

If you can, use `DateSerial` to specifically hook in the month/day numbers without relying on the format output.